# Asking for making Hot Food Smoking, how to make it easier for normal computer?

Tags: physics, smoke-simulation

I want to make the smoking for hot food, but my computer is not that good. This is my Physics Setting, what should I change for better time Baking?
**Domain:**

- Resolution Division: ‘160'
- Adaptive Domain with Threshold: ‘0.001’
- Dissolve with Time: ‘30’
- Tắt Noise, tắt Is Resumable

Comment: Please share a .blend file so that we can best help you. The information you have provided is useful but its best if we are able to see all of the settings that you are working with and try adjusting them ourselves. https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Just as a general advice, of course lower _Resolution Divisions_ bake faster but most likely won't look as you want so that's not the way to go. The other thing you could do is set the _Threshold_ of the _Adaptive Domain_ higher, perhaps 0.01 and you could set the _Time_ for _Dissolve_ lower like 20 or even 15. The problem is, all these things change the look and quality of the smoke so you have to balance between what quality is acceptable and what baking times you can tolerate.